# Aperture 3 - Open first aid options for external library

Tags: troubleshooting, apple-aperture

I have a huge Aperture 3 library that will not open, giving the following message:

`Verify that you have iPhoto 9.4 or later. Then open the library in iPhoto to upgrade it.`.

It is not set as my default Aperture library, so every time I try to access the first aid tools via option + control during launch dose only show the first aid options for the default library.

How can I open the external library with the first aid options?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Aperture user, but it appears that if, instead of opening Aperture and having that load your default library, you can instead double-click on that external library (while holding Command and Option keys) and it should open that library with first aid.

That's what I gather from this article - [Repairing and Rebuilding Your Aperture Library](http://documentation.apple.com/en/aperture/usermanual/index.html#chapter=27&section=10&tasks=true)

Comment: I tried that - but somehow I can't get Aperture to open the first aid menu. I press cmd + alt before and during I click on the library I want to repair. The only thing that happens is that finder closes the current window and Aperture starts regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down Option (only) as you open Aperture to display a list of the libraries known by the app.

Single click the affected library if it is in the list or browse for it with the appropriate button, but hold Command+Option as you click the Open button to access the recovery tools.